# php - get character count between two points encased in quotes

Tags: php

Ok this is going to be weird but I need it

I am trying to get the character count for a huge line of code between some particular quotes ". Basically I need to be able to get everything between the 3rd quote in the beginning and the 5th quote at the end.

So here is an example

```
a:2:{s:10:"categories";s:5758:"...........";s:5:"posts";s:6:"a:0:{}";}
```

I need to know what the character count is of all the periods. There is actually code in place of those periods.

Since there are 11 periods then my character count will be 11. The only consistent thing is the quotes in this so I need to base off that.

Any help would be awesome.

Here is my code. I am basically creating the code and adding some custom labels. I tried serializing the code first before I unserialize it but that didn't seem to work.

```
<?
$thisisit .= 'a:2:{s:10:"categories";s:5481:"a:40:{';
include('connect.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_terms ORDER BY term_id ASC LIMIT 40"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$count = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $name = $row['name'];
    $charactercount = strlen($name);
    $term_id = $row['term_id'];
    $thisisit .= 'i:'.$count.';a:2:{s:11:"filter_name";s:20:"add_keyword_category";s:11:"filter_args";a:7:{s:12:"filter_value";s:'.$charactercount.':"'.strtolower($name).'";s:19:"filter_search_title";s:1:"1";s:21:"filter_search_excerpt";i:0;s:21:"filter_search_content";s:1:"1";s:21:"faf_filter_categories";a:1:{i:4;s:3:"'.$term_id.'";}s:17:"filter_match_word";i:0;s:17:"filter_match_case";i:0;}}';
    //echo "<br><br>";
    $count++;
}
$thisisit .= '}";s:5:"posts";s:6:"a:0:{}";}';

$array = unserialize($thisisit);
echo strlen($array['categories']);
?>
```

Comment: Serialized data. The string is 5758 characters long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this data looks serialized. The correct solution would be to use php function `unserialize`.

Then, given your structure, to know the length of that element:

```
strlen(unserialize($data)['categories']);
```

If you run old php, you need to store the result in a temporary variable:

```
$array = unserialize($data);
echo strlen($array['categories']);
```

If your serialized data is corrupted *(as in "not received from proper execution of `serialize`")*, as it seems from your example, we can return to your original task:

> get everything between the 3rd quote in the beginning and the 5th quote at the end

The simplest way to achieve that is:

```
implode("'", array_slice(explode("'", $data), 3, -5));
```

Comment: shouldnt it be strlen(unserialize($data['categories'])); ? I changed it to this and it returns 0

Comment: No, it shouldn't. You first unserialize the entire string and get an array. Then you take categories out of that array.

Comment: Your version returns Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/content/g/u/i/...../html/....../test.php on line xx

Comment: 5.3 is the version of php that I run

Comment: still returning 0. Let me update my question with my code so you can see

Comment: Now we can see that your data is corrupted and is not proper serialization. I've updated my answer with a workaround based on your original task.